# Why the AJAX function is not getting called and alert is not getting printed upon calling the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, alert

I want to call the ajax function once user clicks on the select control or the select control gets focus to itself from keyboard.

HTML code is as follows :

```
<select id="scanner" name="scanner" class="form-control"></select>
```

The jQuery-AJAX function I wrote is as follows but the aler("Hello") is not getting printed. why so?

```
 $("#scanner").bind("change",function() { alert("Hello");

    var mod_url = $('#mod_url').val(); 

    $.ajax({
      url : mod_url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      data: {
        'request_type':'ajax', 
        'op':'get_all_stores'
      },
      success: function(result, success) { alert(result);
        $('#scanner').html(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error is occured");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: check in firebug or in developer console of browser ,is there any  errors ?

Comment: @Transformer:Tried still no alert from success function too.

Comment: "focus" try with this instead of "change" or bind both like "focus change". select doesn't fire change event from keypress events in some browsers like firefox sometime back.

Comment: using Only keybord ?

Comment: change event triggers only when you change or select the options.Try with click or focus event

Comment: had you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `code` i haven't seen any `options` for html `select` box

And, you have registered a `change` event on `select` box which will occur only on selecting the `options` in `select` box

Add few `options` in select box and try to select options which will fire the ajax call

See [**JS FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/drk01m5h/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this instead:

```
 $("#scanner").bind("focus", function() { 
    alert("Hello");
    var mod_url = $('#mod_url').val(); 
    $.ajax({
      url : mod_url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "html",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        'request_type':'ajax', 
        'op':'get_all_stores'
      },
      success: function(result, success) { 
          alert(result);
          $('#scanner').html(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error is occured");
      }
    });
  });
```

---

And one suggestion about `bind` is, you can use `.on()` method instead if you are using jQuery version `1.7+`.

---

What seems to me you want to generate your `#scanner` elements `options` by your ajax call, so the changes are:

1. remove the `async:false` because ajax has to be asynchronous.
2. change the `dataType` to `html` because it seems that you are returning options from there as `$('#scanner').html(result);` suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I Think This is what you want

```
  $("#scanner").bind('focus',function () {
            Myfunction(); // call what you want to call on focus 
        }).change(function() {
              Myfunction()      // call what you want to call on Change                    
      });



function Myfunction()
{
    var mod_url = "http://google.com"; 

    $.ajax({
      url : mod_url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      data: {
        'request_type':'ajax', 
        'op':'get_all_stores'
      },
      success: function(result, success) { alert(result);
        $('#scanner').html(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error is occured");
      }
    });
}
```

here js fiddle  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/drk01m5h/6/)